# Is this instance variable being “hidden” or not?

Tags: java

How is it that the reference to the hiding variable, varIntA, in the method does not affect the obect being referred to in the method parameters? (Like varIntB is changed?)

```
//   Main.Java 
import main.MainClass;
import sub.SubClass;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SubClass objSC = new SubClass();
        System.out.println("\n before - " + objSC);
        SubClass.subtract( objSC, 25);
        System.out.println("\n after - " + objSC); 
    }
}

//  \main\MainClass.java
package main;

public class MainClass {
    protected int varIntA = 100;
    protected int varIntB = 100;

    public String toString() { return "varIntA: " + varIntA + "   varIntB: " + varIntB; }
}

//   \sub\SubClass.java  
package sub;
import main.MainClass;

public class SubClass extends MainClass {
     public int varIntA;  //  (The access level of varIntA has no effect.)

     static public void subtract( SubClass obj, int n) {
         System.out.println("\n  varIntA = " + obj.varIntA + "  varintB = " + obj.varIntB);
         obj.varIntA -= n;
         obj.varIntB -= n;
         System.out.println("  varIntA = " + obj.varIntA + "  varintB = " + obj.varIntB);       
      }
}
```

Comment: What output do you *expect* and *why*, and how does that differ from what you see?

Comment: Because `SubClass` does not have a `toString()` function so `MainClass.toString()` is called which uses `MainClass.varIntA`.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp not probably, precisely why. @OP Moreover the variable would still be available through `super` in the subclass, all you've achieved is two separate variables (there is no "overshadowing" variables, only a lack of definitive, unambiguous references).

Comment: @Rogue Yes, I edited and removed that word :)

Comment: Sorry.  I got so involved in trying to get the code indented that I forgot.  The OP from the method shows varIntA going from zero to -25, which makes sense.  The OP from the Main class shows the varIntA staying at 100.  There is only one object, I presume, how can there be a discrepancy?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are two `varIntA` member variables.  The `subtract` method is going to work on the `varIntA` in `SubClass`, but the `toString` method is going to print the value of the `varIntA` in `MainClass`.

Redefining `varIntA` in `SubClass` is hiding the superclass's `varIntA` from the subclass, but not from any of the code in `MainClass`.

So when you run this code, only `varIntB` in the MainClass class will be reduced by 25.  So at the end, you should see this line printed:

```
after - varIntA: 100   varIntB: 75
```

The `varIntA` in `SubClass` will end up with a value of `-25`.

[This web page](https://dzone.com/articles/variable-shadowing-and-hiding-in-java#:%7E:text=What%20Is%20variable%20Hiding%3F,thus%20hiding%20the%20inherited%20variable.) explains what's going on here pretty well.  See the section "What is Variable Hiding?".

Comment: Yes.  You are blowing my mind!  How many objects are created?  If you could explain quickly, that would be great.  Or could you point me to a resource that might?  Thanks!

Comment: Only one object is being created, because you're only calling `new` once.  It's just that that object has three member variables in it, two of which are named `varIntA`.

Comment: See the documentation reference I added to the bottom of my answer.

Comment: I am reading it now.  At first blush, it seems to indicate the object.field references should be consistent since the reference type is to SubMain in both the method argument and the object declaration.  But maybe it is being implicitly upcast by the toString() method inherited from Main?  I will experiment further.  Thanks Again.

Comment: P.S.  I should have said that the toString() is inherited from MainClass.

Comment: P.P.S.  Which is how those guys first nailed it.  Thank You Everyone.